# SQL Server Profiler ignore a big query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Server profiler for capture query. I am able to see my query in profiler but when I pass a big nvarchar(max) parameter's value, - query is not logged.
How can I capture a big query?

I am using SQL Server Profiler v17.9.1

Comment: The best way to tackle this would be to use extended events instead of profiler.

Comment: the sql server profiler put hard effect on your server and make it slow the best solution is use to extended  event, query store or monitoring app like APEX SQL and new app in latest version SQL Server management studio

Comment: @SeanLange extended events ignore a big query as well